# jqGrid JSON Data Can't Shown On Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, jqgrid

I want to show a JSON data at my table as like here: [example](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

I used that CSS imports:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ui.jqgrid.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/ui.multiselect.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/jquery-ui-1.8.1.custom.css"/>
```

That JS imports:

```
<script type=text/javascript src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript src="/js/jquery_ui_1.8.1.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript src="/js/jquery.layout.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript src="/js/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
    $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui.multiselect.js"></script>
<script type=text/javascript src="/js/jgrid_4.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.tablednd.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.contextmenu.js"></script>
```

(Some files has different name but they are OK)

I am getting a JSON data from an URL and when I check it it comes correctly at Firebug. 
That's my HTML data:

```
<table id="confTable"></table>
<div id="pconfTable"></div>
```

That's my script to populate data:

```
jQuery("#confTable").jqGrid({ ajaxGridOptions : {type:"GET"}, serializeGridData : function(postdata) {
            postdata.page = 1;
            return postdata;
        }, url:'/ui/webapp/conf', datatype: 'json', colNames:['Value','Type', 'Target Module', 'Configuration Group', 'Name', 'Description', 'Identity', 'Version', 'System Id', 'Active'],
            colModel:[
                {name:'value',index:'value', width:55},
                {name:'type',index:'type', width:55},
                {name:'targetModule',index:'targetModule', width:150},
                {name:'configurationGroup',index:'configurationGroup', width:180},
                {name:'name',index:'name asc', width:90},
                {name:'description',index:'description', width:90},
                {name:'identity',index:'identity', width:90},
                {name:'version',index:'version', width:90},
                {name:'systemId',index:'systemId', width:100},
                {name:'active',index:'active', width:100}
            ], rowNum:10, width:980, rowList:[10,20,30], pager: '#pconfTable', sortname: 'name', viewrecords: true, sortorder: "desc", caption:"Configuration Information" });
        jQuery("#pconfTable").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pconfTable', {edit:false,add:false,del:false});
```

That's JSON data that I get:

```
[{
        "value":"10",
        "type":"Tip 1",
        "targetModule":"Target 1",
        "configurationGroup":null,
        "name":"Configuration Deneme 1",
        "description":null,
        "identity":"Configuration Deneme 1",
        "version":0,
        "systemId":0,
        "active":true
    },
    {
        "value":"50",
        "type":"Tip 2",
        "targetModule":"Target 2",
        "configurationGroup":null,
        "name":"Configuration Deneme 2",
        "description":null,
        "identity":"Configuration Deneme 2",
        "version":0,
        "systemId":0,
        "active":true
    },
    {
        "value":"100",
        "type":"Tip 3",
        "targetModule":"Target 3",
        "configurationGroup":null,
        "name":"Configuration Deneme 3",
        "description":null,
        "identity":"Configuration Deneme 3",
        "version":0,
        "systemId":0,
        "active":true
    }
]
```

I have formatted indentation to be read easiliy.

However I don't get any error from Firebug and don't have any can't imported files I still have an empty table.

Any ideas?

**PS:** Is there anything wrong with my JSON data, should I  send a data starts as like => total: xxx, page: yyy, records: zzz, rows: or not a must?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see the grid filled you should use the following [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#jsonreader_as_function) as additional jqGrid parameter

```
jsonReader: {
    repeatitems: false,
    id: "value",
    root: function (obj) { return obj; },
    page: function (obj) { return 1; },
    total: function (obj) { return 1; },
    records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
}
```

I suppose, that the values from the `'value'` column are unique, so I used `id: "value"` in the `jsonReader` above.

By the way the `ajaxGridOptions : {type:"GET"}` do nothing. The default `mtype: 'GET'` do the same. In the call of `navGrid` method you should use `jQuery("#confTable")` instead of `jQuery("#pconfTable")`.

After the described changed you will have the following [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/kamaci.htm). In the demo I added `height: 'auto'` to have less empty space in the grid.

Comment: @kamaci: It should not work because you don't use `loadonce:true` option and the sorting and paging should be **on the server side**. Because I use just your JSON data saved in the file the server get back the same data sorted by 'name' ASC like in your JSON.

Comment: One more, can I close the search button at left down?

Comment: so if I change "loadonce:true" to false does it  sort it at **client side** this maybe solution => http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/jqgrid-loadonce-problem/, I will check

Comment: @kamaci: "loadonce:true" means loading the data **once** and local sorting, paging and filtering. see [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/kamaci-loadonce.htm). You can use even local paging and filtering of data (like [toolbar searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching) and [advanced searching](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:advanced_searching)). You should sort only the **initial data** loaded from the server and use additional column settings like `sorttype: 'int'` to have more correct sorting order.

Comment: @kamaci: I can't follow you. What you want to have? If you write 'change "loadonce:true" to false' you mean "loadonce:false" which is default setting and it's the same what you have at the beginning. In the case you have to implement sorting, paging and optionally filtering/searching **on the server side**. By the way [the reference](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/jqgrid-loadonce-problem/) is from 2009. At the time the setting `loadonce` is not exist. It is described the main idea of what `loadonce` do.

Comment: thanks for your help, my application runs well and has sorting ability. Before voting up accepting as an answer just I want to learn that. There is a search button at left bottom. Can I disappear it?

Comment: @kamaci: You are welcome! You can use add `search:false` to the `navGrid` options: `jQuery("#confTable").jqGrid('navGrid', '#pconfTable', {edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false})`. See [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#parameters) for details.